# Need to poll a bunch of web services from a Linux server - What is the most efficient way?

Tags: linux, web-services, polling

So basically, I'm looking to build a web app that aggregates a bunch of data from various web services and presents the data visually. To achieve what I want, I will basically need to regularly poll these web services, and store the resulting data from each call in a database. This data would then be queried by the web app etc.

I'm looking to build the web app using PHP (code igniter), but I'm not entirely sure how to go about the polling component. I'm coming from a .NET background and still getting used to the Linux/web world. I would normally solve this problem by simply writing a .NET Windows Service... I want all of this to run on a linux box however, so if anyone could recommend any technologies for this sort of thing that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How often do you want to poll the web services? If it is several minutes consider [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: The posix analog of a windows service is a daemon so that's probably what you want.  If you need less granular polling you can consider Basile's suggestion of cron which is the equivalent of (I think) a window's task which you can set up to repeatedly run your program from every few minutes to hours or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers... I'm looking at polling quite frequently. Somewhere in the order of once per web service per minute... I did look in to a daemon being the best option. Can daemons be written in languages other than C? My C skills at that sort of level are extremely limited to say the least.